# Persistent Code Memoization in Compilers and Run-Times Environments

Tags: performance, persistence, code-reuse, memoization

I believe the concept of a code-cache (for example [ccache](http://ccache.samba.org/)) should be extended into a more *fine-grained memoization* of both intermediate code (IC) and target code (TC) in compilers such as GCC or LLVM+Clang.

This can then be used for a whole range of ground-breaking cleverness benefiting both programmer *productivity* and compile-, run-time performance and run-time memory usage.

More specifically, this repository (or database) should automatically *cache* IC and TC of functions. These can then be looked up and *reused* in different sets of builds (compiled only once link many) in across sets of programs and libraries and not just across object boundaries during linking (LTO).

This would especially benefit C++ STL container-algorithm-instantiations. For example how many times hasn't algorithms such `std::sort` applied on `std::vector<T>` been instantiated and optimized and compiled in different programs using the same type `T` typically `int`, `float` and `double`?

In an implementation, IC-modules should be indexed by keys constructed from [hash-chain](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Hash_chain) (SHA-1 should suffice) of compiler configuration and IC-code-tree (including the sub-tree-code-hashes of the functions it calls) and stored in for example an `std::unordered_map` providing very *cheap lookups*. To even further promote reuse of code the IC-repository could be put *online* as *network-service*.

Of course the memoizations should only be cached when needed for optimal good performance. This should have a very small overhead. As most hash-keys lookups should be misses the keys should be placed in memory but not necessarily the code-snippets.

This [project](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http://www.stanford.edu/%257Epgbovine/projects/pubs/guo_issta11_camera_ready.pdf&ei=6T64TqroE9LY4QTamq3IAw&usg=AFQjCNFEFlHJyCnEHr3eLY2jRVXhldCmtg&sig2=9S_y8ageSpzvBH9u_sooTg) has already proved the usefulness of this idea applied to the Python language. I believe Haskell (GHC) may be the ideal language for experimenting with these ideas because of its default function purity and flexible control on function side-effects.

Comment: Oh, I notice that you have completely changed the structure of your question. Great. I will delete my answer then.

Comment: Generating code is cheap. While repeated template instanciations with `-O3` may be some work for the compiler, a somewhat beefy computer (especially when it's a dedicated build server) can handle thousands of those per second and for all but the largest programs, nobody would notice any difference. I don't think this is worth cutting compilers open and adjusting their internals, especially since the required changes may be vast and complicated. Add to that the overhead of disk I/O or even network latency and you're in the red for most cases. Still +1 for an interesting idea.